# set condition on kendo grid table field using template

Tags: templates, gridview, kendo-ui, conditional-statements

set kendo template condtion when id is null

```
<div id="grid">
    <script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
        <tr> 
            <td> #= id #</td>
            <td> #= FirstName # </td>
            <td> #= LastName # </td> 
        </tr>
    </script>

    <script id="detailTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
        <p>detail stuff</p>
    </script>

</div>
```

data source :

```
dataSource: {
              data: [
                  {
                      id:"",
                      FirstName: "Joe",
                      LastName: "Smith"
                  },
                  {
                      id:"1",
                      FirstName: "Jane",
                      LastName: "Smith"
                  }]
    },
```

here is first id is null
i want to set there some text like `TEST`
how can i do this.

thanks.
here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yzKqV/180/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a template for the `id` as:

```
<script id="idTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    # if (id) { #
        #= id #
    # } else { #
        TEST
    # } #
</script>
```

and then in the columns definition do:

```
columns:[
    {    
        field: "id",
        title: "id",
        template: $("#idTemplate").html()

    },     
    {
        field: "FirstName",
        title: "First Name"
    },
    {
        field: "LastName",
        title: "Last Name"
    }
],
```

Your JSFiddle modified using this idea: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/yzKqV/184/

*NOTE*: Defining a `rowTemplate` when using details is not that easy since you template has to deal with drawing the handle for opening details.